# What is the precise difference in age between B4, Lore and Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data

Memory Alpha provides vague dates of them all being activated in the 2330s, but is there actually any reference to a more precise age difference between the three brothers in *any* Trek materials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is another of those questions that has most likely not yet had a canonical answer. However, Memory Alpha does have some clues that could be strung together to give an approximate date for at least some of it.

[MA](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Lore) states:

> Lore was a Soong-type android constructed by Doctor Noonian Soong and
>   Juliana Soong at the Omicron Theta colony and activated on 9
>   September, 2335.

Design and construction of Data probably started soon after that, following heated discussions between Julianna and Noonien Soong (alluded to in [TNG: Inheritance](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28episode%29)).

Data was activated some time before the [Crystalline Entity attacked Omicron Theta in 2336](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Crystalline_Entity), so to give a reasonable amount of time for development of Data's positronic net as outlined in "Inheritance", it's best to assume the Entity attacked in late 2336 (mostly taken from [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Data#Creation_and_early_life)).

She relates to Data that she and Dr. Soong had created and lost three prototypes prior to Lore, and it's [generally accepted](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/B-4) that B-4 is one of them. Again hypothesising, based on a comparison of Julianna's account of Data's early years, Data's own account of an early dilemma about his own development in [TNG: Eye of the Beholder](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_%28episode%29) and B-4's shown behaviour, B-4 could be taken to be the third prototype - advanced enough for his positronic net to adapt and evolve.

Since it took around a year to develop Data following Lore's deactivation, and that Data was in fact a step backwards in technical excellence (the famous "I am not less perfect than Lore" concept from [Datalore](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Datalore_%28episode%29) and [Family](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Family_%28episode%29%E2%80%8E)), it might be safe to assume that the gap between B-4 and Lore was a year to two years in length. Which puts B-4's activation somewhere around late 2333 to early 2334.

Happy for others to add more evidence. The many published timelines don't seem to have much information about the Soong androids.

Comment: A very well-researched answer.