# How long did it take to build Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228457/38110), I created a timeline based on what we learn about the Crystal Entity on-screen.

In my own answer, I make a speculative case for the entity probably being delayed and Soong building Data fairly quickly, but this speculation is based on not much.

Additionally, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55457/38110) claims that "it took a year to construct Data following Lore's deactivation", but does not provide any sources for both claims (one, that it took a year to build Data, and two, that the construction of Data started after Lore's deactivation, and not before).

So I would like to know: How long did it take to build Data? I also accept any insights the Star Trek books might give us, since I don't believe the series ever addressed this.

Comment: For what little it's worth, I suspect the assumption that Data's construction began after Lore's deactivation comes from a line in 'Brothers' where Soong says that after he deactivated Lore for being unstable, the next logical step was to create Data, with the intent of going back and "fixing" Lore later.

Comment: I always thought that the plans for creating Data where already very advanced, or Data was even already under development when Lore was active, simply due to the fact that when we meet Lore, he seems to be very aware about who Data is.

Comment: That is an inconsistency to be sure, though it presupposes that Lore was being truthful, which we know he was not. Indeed Soong directly contradicted him by saying that he and Data were nearly identical, save for some programming. That indicates that Data was an iteration on Lore and not developed from scratch, which means he was almost certainly built after the fact. Which makes sense because why would Soong be making a new android *before* the previous one failed?

Comment: He knows who Data is, in enough detail to know that Data is supposed to be built without emotions, to fix  what made Lore evil. So Lore was still active long enough after turning evil to learn from this. Their "mother", Julianna, has implied that she regarded Lore and Data as their children, so it's possible that they postponed turning off Lore until he became unbearable, but started working on Data before that.

Comment: He's an android and a very devious one at that. Data was right there when he was reactivated so it wouldn't have taken him more than a few milliseconds to deduce who Data was and concoct a while story to gain his trust. And as stated, 'Brothers' established that the whole "you were a less perfect version of me" line was a falsity, so why trust anything else he says?

Comment: I am not saying it was like that - all I am saying is that there are scenarios where the construction of Data could have been started before Lore was deactivated. Without any evidence, we can only speculate - hence the question.

Comment: As I said. Soong specifically said he made Data *after* he dismantled Lore. All other evidence to the contrary comes from an unreliable source. Still, if we look at this logically: in an age of replicators it probably wouldn't have taken any time at all to fabricate Data's body, or at least the constituent components prior to assembly (especially since Soong had already made several outwardly identical ones by that point.) The tricky & time consuming part would have been creating the neural net & programming his personality; both of which could only have been started after Lore became unstable

Comment: Can you provide the quote or episode where he said that? Regarding the second half of your comment: please take a look at the answer I linked to on my question, where I have also provided some speculation as to why constructing data might have been done fairly quickly.

Comment: I already specified that quote came from 'Brothers', but if you must have it word-for word:-
"...it was easier just to turn your back and build your precious Data."
"You were the first. You meant as much to me as Data ever did. But you were unstable..."
"Why didn't you just fix me? It was within your power to fix me."
"It wasn't as easy as that. The next logical step was to construct Data. Afterward, I planned to get back to you, to fix you."
We can speculate all we like--bottom line: we don't have anything close to a clear timeline of any of this, only a rough sequence of events

Comment: This quote proves a lot: That Data came after Lore, that Lore doesn't understand why Soong created Data, and that fixing Lore was not easy. Unfortunately, however, it does not prove that Lore was deactivated before the construction of Data began. It's impossible to say without context, and it's easy to argue for either side given the quote and the other bits and pieces we know from episodes involving Lore.